# Use slash commands to make rest calls in Slack

Tags: python, rest, parse-cloud-code, slack-api

so at work my team uses slack, and we thought it would be cool if we could us a slash command to modify some of our Parse tables (we have a lot of cloud code that we want to turn off and on for maintenance). Supposedly you can add get/post requests to different slashes, but I don't see how you can modify the header. I want to run the following rest call (this is the python version)

```
import json,httplib,urllib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/1/functions/activateCloud', json.dumps({
     }), {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx",
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
#don't need to print anything, just what I was using for testing
```

Comment: You could spin up your own middlelayer which in turn calls your cloud

Comment: yea that does it, just kinda a little pain haha. I was hoping there was a quick step solution.